# How to implement generic converter using angular/fire modular API?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I've been banging my head around for the past two days with this issue, so I would like to know if anybody can point me in the right direction.

I'm migrating our old @angular/fire compat API to the new modular API. We had implemented a generic way of retrieving data like so:

```
get<T extends DbModel>(TCreator: new () => T, id: string, refParams: any = undefined): Observable<T | undefined> {
    let o = new TCreator();
    return this._afs.doc<T>(`${o.getRef(refParams)}/${id}`)
      .valueChanges().pipe(
        map(value => {
          return value ? { ...value, id } : value;
        })
      );
  }
```

The important method of DbCLass is getRef and basically will return the collection path of the class that extends it. The class looks like this:

```
export abstract class DbModel {
    [index: string]: any;
    abstract getRef(refParams: any): string;
    getGroupName(): string { throw new Error('Group name not set'); }
    id!: string;
}
```

The problem comes that in the modular API, the doc method can't specify a type like this and after reading the documentation I found that I should write a converter to do this. Here is the generic converter I implemented:

```
private _converter = <T>() => ({
    toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data,
    fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>) => snap.data()
  })
```

And here when trying to use it is where the problem arises:

```
getModular<T extends DbModel>(TCreator: new () => T, id: string, refParams: any = undefined) : Observable<T | undefined> {
    let instance = new TCreator();
    let docRef = doc(this._afsModular, `${instance.getRef(refParams)}/${id}`)
                  .withConverter(this._converter<T>());
  }
```

The error I get is:

Overload 2 of 2, '(converter: FirestoreDataConverter): DocumentReference', gave the following error.
Argument of type '{ toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue) => PartialWithFieldValue; fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => T; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirestoreDataConverter'.
Types of property 'fromFirestore' are incompatible.
Type '(snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => T' is not assignable to type '(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot, options?: SnapshotOptions | undefined) => T'.
Types of parameters 'snap' and 'snapshot' are incompatible.
Property 'isEqual' is missing in type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' but required in type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(9611, 5): 'isEqual' is declared here.

Basically, 'DocumentSnapshot<T = DocumentData>', which is extended by 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T = DocumentData>' has this method that 'DocumentSnapshot' does not have:

```
/**
     * Returns true if this `DocumentSnapshot` is equal to the provided one.
     *
     * @param other The `DocumentSnapshot` to compare against.
     * @return true if this `DocumentSnapshot` is equal to the provided one.
     */
    isEqual(other: DocumentSnapshot<T>): boolean;
```

So my question is, how can I correctly implement this generic converter without having this error?

Thanks in advance!

Thorough explanation in the detail section

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this for anyone who maybe has a similar problem and hasn't noticed why. I am working with the compat and the modular API simultaneously while I migrate my whole codebase to Angular Fire v7.

The problem I experienced was because the QueryDocumentSnapshot class was being imported from the compat instead of the modular API, which caused the issues with the types.

Silly mistake, but I won't erase the question so everyone who is working with both APIs remembers to check their imports haha, happy migration!